How to make listen only do 1 command at once?
So I have a movement script for my turtle (called mc)
from turtle import *

def w():
    mc.shape(FFM1)
    mc.forward(40)
    mc.shape(FFM2)
    mc.forward(40)
    mc.shape(FFS)

def s():
    mc.shape(BFM1)
    mc.bk(40)
    mc.shape(BFM2)
    mc.bk(40)
    mc.shape(BFS)

def a():
    mc.shape(LFM1)
    mc.setx(mc.xcor() - 40)
    mc.shape(LFM2)
    mc.setx(mc.xcor() - 40)
    mc.shape(LFS)

def d():
    mc.shape(RFM1)
    mc.setx(mc.xcor() + 40)
    mc.shape(RFM2)
    mc.setx(mc.xcor() + 40)
    mc.shape(RFS)

wn.onkey(w, "w")
wn.onkey(s, "s") # "Back"
#         ^^^^
wn.onkey(a, "a")
wn.onkey(d, "d")

listen()
mainloop()

This works but if I press, for example, d more than once while turtle is still moving it carries on moving however when it stops it teleports back to where it should have gone from the first move.
I've tried putting a time.sleep(2) in the function but it doesn't do anything and just freezes the turtle for two seconds and then carries on breaking

Is this your complete script? I get NameError: name 'wn' is not defined. Did you mean: 'w'?. What Python version do you use? Do you use Windows?

Please update the code to include your actual code--this isn't runnable. Thanks. It's a bit strange that you're using forward and back on one axis, then setx on the other axis. Why not use rotation and forward exclusively? I'm not sure what sort of movement you want to create (I suggest clarifying how you want behavior to be, exactly), but this answer provides a good starter for full real-time smooth movement, if that's what you're looking for.

sorry wn is a screen and I just want a basic wasd movement, w forward, a left, s backwards and d right

Please [edit] the question to provide runnable code as a [mcve].

Marked as a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79215316/4788546.

You can add a variable and a condition to allow only one movement at a time:
from turtle import *

moving = False
def w():
    global moving
    if not moving:
        moving = True
        mc.shape(FFM1)
        mc.forward(40)
        mc.shape(FFM2)
        mc.forward(40)
        mc.shape(FFS)
        moving = False

def s():
    global moving
    if not moving:
        moving = True
        mc.shape(BFM1)
        mc.bk(40)
        mc.shape(BFM2)
        mc.bk(40)
        mc.shape(BFS)
        moving = False

def a():
    global moving
    if not moving:
        moving = True
        mc.shape(LFM1)
        mc.setx(mc.xcor() - 40)
        mc.shape(LFM2)
        mc.setx(mc.xcor() - 40)
        mc.shape(LFS)
        moving = False

def d():
    global moving
    if not moving:
        moving = True
        mc.shape(RFM1)
        mc.setx(mc.xcor() + 40)
        mc.shape(RFM2)
        mc.setx(mc.xcor() + 40)
        mc.shape(RFS)
        moving = False

wn.onkey(w, "w")
wn.onkey(s, "s")
wn.onkey(a, "a")
wn.onkey(d, "d")

listen()
mainloop()


you are missing updating the moving variable to True where needed.

@jsbueno Thank you. I had it in my local code, but forgot it in the OP's code.

This seens prone to race-condition errors - what if a second function kicks in between the if not moving scenario and setting movingto True?
That could happen in multithreading code. Maybe you could use a threading.Lock instance, instead of the boolean variable - along the with statement - that would not only ensure the correct behavior, but also sabe you two lines in each function.

@jsbueno I wanted to keep this a simple as possible. I'm not sure the OP understands the problem and this simple solution. I answered the posted question not a potential other question.
