How to make listen() wait between inputs?
So I have a movement script for my turtle (called mc)
from turtle import *

wn = Screen()
MC=Turtle()

def w():
    mc.shape(FFM1)
    mc.forward(40)
    mc.shape(FFM2)
    mc.forward(40)
    mc.shape(FFS)

def s():
    mc.shape(BFM1)
    mc.bk(40)
    mc.shape(BFM2)
    mc.bk(40)
    mc.shape(BFS)

def a():
    mc.shape(LFM1)
    mc.setx(mc.xcor() - 40)
    mc.shape(LFM2)
    mc.setx(mc.xcor() - 40)
    mc.shape(LFS)

def d():
    mc.shape(RFM1)
    mc.setx(mc.xcor() + 40)
    mc.shape(RFM2)
    mc.setx(mc.xcor() + 40)
    mc.shape(RFS)

wn.onkey(w, "w")
wn.onkey(s, "s") # "Back"
#         ^^^^
wn.onkey(a, "a")
wn.onkey(d, "d")

listen()
mainloop()

This works but if I press, for example, d more than once while turtle is still moving it carries on moving however when it stops it teleports back to where it should have gone from the first move.
I've tried putting a time.sleep(2) in the function but it doesn't do anything and just freezes the turtle for two seconds and then carries on breaking

Your code does NOT work (compile). [SO]: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Check [SO]: How do I ask a good question? or
[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))
for more asking related details.
Also, [JonSkeet.CodeBlog]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION might be a good point to start.

This is basically a repost of this question. Please edit the original question so that it's compliant instead of abandoning it and the comments/work already done on it and reposting it, which adds more noise to the site and makes it harder to use for future visitors. If you must repost, at least heed the requests for a [mcve] in the original question so users don't need to repeat asking for that all over again, as has happened here. Thanks.

Listing [Python.Docs]: turtle - Turtle graphics. Please read the documentation of the functions you are using and others as well.
Problems:

listen does not wait for user inputs

You got the whole movement scheme wrong. The turtle moves (in this case) by a step to a certain direction. You never change the direction (default is 0° (right, east)), so no matter which of the 4 keys you press it will only move along the X axis


As a consequence, code in the question cannot work (not to mention undefined variables like FFS). I modified the script to work properly (also added some improvements).
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import turtle


# @TODO - cfati: Added these to get rid of errors. Remove them
FFM1 = None
FFM2 = None
FFS = None
BFM1 = None
BFM2 = None
BFS = None
LFM1 = None
LFM2 = None
LFS = None
RFM1 = None
RFM2 = None
RFS = None

screen = turtle.Screen()
obj = turtle.Turtle()
step = 20


def up():
    obj.seth(90)
    obj.shape(FFM1)
    obj.forward(step)
    obj.shape(FFM2)
    obj.forward(step)
    obj.shape(FFS)


def down():
    obj.seth(270)
    obj.shape(BFM1)
    obj.forward(step)
    obj.shape(BFM2)
    obj.forward(step)
    obj.shape(BFS)


def left():
    obj.seth(180)
    obj.shape(LFM1)
    obj.forward(step)
    obj.shape(LFM2)
    obj.forward(step)
    obj.shape(LFS)


def right():
    obj.seth(0)
    obj.shape(RFM1)
    obj.forward(step)
    obj.shape(RFM2)
    obj.forward(step)
    obj.shape(RFS)


def main(*argv):
    obj.speed(0)
    screen.onkey(up, "w")
    screen.onkey(down, "s")
    screen.onkey(left, "a")
    screen.onkey(right, "d")
    # @TODO - cfati: These bindings can be removed as well
    screen.onkey(turtle.bye, "Escape")
    screen.onkey(obj.clear, "Return")
    screen.onkeypress(up, "Up")
    screen.onkeypress(down, "Down")
    screen.onkeypress(left, "Left")
    screen.onkeypress(right, "Right")

    turtle.listen()
    turtle.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Here's a print screen example:

